# Using a StringBuilder in a try-catch block in MVC4 app prompts for domain credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a weird problem.  I am use C# in MVC4.  I have anonymous auth turned off and domain auth turned on.  This problem occurs on my local system (using local IIS for debug) and on a remote server.  Authentication works automatically and properly on both systems under normal circumstances.

I have two C# MVC4 applications (.NET 4.5) that use a StringBuilder object inside a try-catch block.  I've noted in both applications, one with the try block, the other in the catch that if the StringBuilder is referenced, the system prompts for domain credentials and won't except my credentials, eventually giving up and failing with the following errors:

```
0: error
12030  -- connection error or connection reset
12031  -- connection error or connection reset
```

Search engine reveals bit more info about the errors:

> **ERROR_WINHTTP_CONNECTION_ERROR 12030** The connection with the server
>   has been reset or terminated, or an incompatible SSL protocol was
>   encountered. For example, WinHTTP version 5.1 does not support SSL2
>   unless the client specifically enables it.
>
> **Error Code 12031 FTP Connection to the server was reset**.. could not
>   make a connection.

None of these actually identify my problem and seem to be more related to permissioning issues than the real problem.  Also these errors override my descriptive error so I lose the real error that I actually want to see in the client.

I've tried this under my regular domain account and also a more-elevated domain admin account.  Neither works.  I should mention I'm using Telerik's new beta scheduler control in this example, but it happens under another Telerik project.  The problem doesn't pertain to anything doing anything with Telerik, however.

Using domain auth, this example still prompts for authentication:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";


        return View();
    }
}

public ActionResult someAjax()
{
    try
    {
        throwAnError();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string msg = returnErrorMsg(e);

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(
        System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, msg);
    }

    return Json("I sent a valid value");
}

string throwAnError()
{
    throw new Exception("Something bad happened");
}

string returnErrorMsg(Exception exc)
{
    //return exc.Message;  // this doesn't prompt for credentials.

    StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();
    sbError.AppendLine(exc.Message);
    return sbError.ToString();
}
}
```

On the Index.cshtml file (I've included jquery and Index.js elsewhere):

```
<button id="clickBtn">My Button</button>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Index.js:

```
$("#clickBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/someAjax',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#value").text(data);
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
    .error(function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#value").text(textStatus);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hard to believe that a StringBuilder causes any of that. Post actual code and complete error messages.

Comment: Edited with a crude example.

Comment: What exactly is `DataSourceRequestAttribute` on your 1st input parameter doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `AppendLine` to `Append`:

```
string returnErrorMsg(Exception exc)
{
    //return exc.Message;  // this doesn't prompt for credentials.

    StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();
    sbError.Append(exc.Message);
    return sbError.ToString();
}
```

That should solve the problem. You are going low-level so extra "\r\n" at the end screws response format.

Comment: Way to go, Nenad!  Sure enough.  Even adding the "\r\n" to .Append() does the same thing!  I would upvote this if my reputation would allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help to you somehow?

> **ERROR_WINHTTP_CONNECTION_ERROR 12030** The connection with the server has been reset or terminated, or an incompatible SSL protocol
>   was encountered. For example, WinHTTP version 5.1 does not support
>   SSL2 unless the client specifically enables it.
>
> Error Code **12031** FTP Connection to the server was reset..  could
>   not make a connection.

Comment: That would be one of the errors, and I researched this thoroughly the first time it showed up in a project.  The problem is, the error is a symptom of the real problem, which is the incorrect prompting for permissions for trying to return the real error.

In this case, that error is a fake exception I made up, but it gets replaced by these types or errors or a server 401.

Comment: It works fine if there is no error.  In this example the prompt only occurs if 2 things are true: 1) there is an error, and 2) I use StringBuilder to return the result.

In another project, the error shows up if I create my own error instead of throwing an exception and return a server error with my own custom message.

Comment: Can you then make simple example with StringBuilder and throwing exception that reproduces your problem? Without all Telerik stuff that has nothing to do with the issue as you stated yourself.